# RxJava Retrofit make multiple requests for id

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have JSON

> {    "cameras" : [

> ```
>   {
>      "archives" : [
>         {
>            "accessPoint" : "xxxx",
>            "default" : true,
>            "isEmbedded" : false,
>            "storage" : "xxxx",
>            "storageDisplayName" : "xxxx"
>         }
>      ],
>      "audioStreams" : [],
>      "comment" : "",
>      "detectors" : [
>         {
>            "accessPoint" : "xxxx",
>            "displayName" : "",
>            "events" : [ "SceneChangeDetected" ],
>            "isActivated" : true,
>            "parentDetector" : "",
>            "type" : "xxxx"
>         },
>         {
>            "accessPoint" : "xxxx",
>            "displayName" : "",
>            "events" : [ "xxx" ],
>            "isActivated" : true,
>            "parentDetector" : "",
>            "type" : "xxxx"
>         }
>      ],
>      "displayId" : "1",
>      "displayName" : "xxx",
>      "ipAddress" : "0.0.0.0",
>      "isActivated" : true,
>      "latitude" : "xxxx",
>      "longitude" : "xxx",
>      "model" : "Virtual",
>      "offlineDetectors" : [],
>      "ptzs" : [],
>      "textSources" : [],
>      "vendor" : "AxxonSoft",
>      "videoStreams" : [
>         {
>            "accessPoint" : "xxx
>         }
>      ]
>   },      "archives" : [
> ```

POJO

> public class allCameras {
> @SerializedName("cameras")
> @Expose
> private ArrayList camera;
>
> ```
> public ArrayList<Camera> getCameras() {
>     return camera;
> }
>
> public void setCameras(ArrayList<Camera> cameras) {
>     this.camera = cameras;
> }
> ```

> public class Camera {
> @SerializedName("archives")
> @Expose
> private ArrayList archives;
>
> ```
> @SerializedName("displayName")
> @Expose
> private String displayName;
>
> public ArrayList<Archive> getArchives() {
>     return archives;
> }
>
> public void setArchives(ArrayList<Archive> archives) {
>     this.archives = archives;
> }
>
> public String getDisplayName() {
>     return displayName;
> }
>
> public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
>     this.displayName = displayName;
> }
> ```

And I have a code in which I get the List with the help of RXJAVA
Next, I wanted to combine two requests and pass the execution result (id) from one to the other

But I am faced with a problem: in order for this to work, I must receive one Camera object at a time and pass its ID to another function
But I can only get a ArrayList

Help, please, what to do?

Comment: flatMap can be used to convert an element to zero or more elements that can be observerd on.

Comment: I try to do something like this

.flatMapIterable(list -> list.getCameras().stream())

But i have error: no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Stream<Camera> conforms to Iterable<? extends U